# How to rename a batch of files with an incrementing number in the file name?

Tags: batch, batch-rename

I want to rename batch of files named Example1.java, Example2.java to Q1.java, Q2.java at once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The rename command in terminal is a useful script that will take care of this for you using the simple VIM-style search and replace command.  Assuming you have nothing else of the form Example*.java in your directory:

`$ rename 's/Example/Q/' Example*.java`

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was a software called `Bulk Rename` in good old days of Ubuntu 7.10. I've searched for the package and i couldn't find it. But i've found another package [Here](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-renamer). Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Renamer?content=87601

Good nautilus script. Let you preview before renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Little bash script:

```
for file in Example*.java
do
  mv "$file" "${file/Example/Q}"
done
```

But still the question is duplicate, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450818/rename-all-files-in-directory-from-filename-h-to-filename-half) :)